# How to create a page for database entries in a html page

Tags: html, mysql, sql, database

At the moment I have this database:

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|     Project         |     Task         |
|---------------------|------------------|
|        id           |      id          |
|---------------------|------------------|
|    project_name     |   task_name      |
|---------------------|------------------|
                      |   project_id(FK) |
                      |------------------|
```

The supplies table, has a list for (name of the item or task) (id) and the project it is assigned to via a foreign key.

I have a simple post HTML form that lets users fill it out, and that in turn updates the database

Now I'm looking to add a sort of "output" that lets me create hyperlinks (or small pages) to each project, so that users can have the option to delete the project/add new tasks into it and so on

The only part I'm struggling on is figuring out how to create a seperate type page, I have tried using this

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assos($result)) {
echo "<li>" . "<a href=clientportal.php?project_id={$row['id']}'> 
{$row['name']}</a>" . "</li>";
}
```

But this creates a HTTP 500 error, which I assume is because I used post and not get in my form.

Is there another way to do what I am looking for? or should I go back to my form and change it to a get method

Ideally I'm looking for a simple list of current projects, with hyperlinks, that take me to a page where I can add some php/sql code to output a few simple SQL query options as mentioned, such as deleting the project, adding a new task etc.

Thank you!